# Is “random arousal” in humans still caused by/connected to “background” sex drive?

Tags: reproduction, human-physiology, endocrinology, sex, sexuality

I’m not sure if the title is the best way to word the concept but I don’t know how else to put it briefly; though honestly this question itself might be a bit hard for me to communicate concisely in text so if any more clarification on my thoughts or question is needed, then just ask.

So what I’m curious about is the origin of spontaneous erections (e.g. those not caused by conscious sexual stimulation of any kind be it visual, mental, or physical; for example “morning wood”, or other “random” erections that can occur during the day unprompted) and how libido plays into those, since a drop or loss of libido is typically reportedly accompanied by a lack of these spontaneous erections including the “morning wood”. Even though this behavior of the body isn’t directly and consciously caused by active sexual stimulation (but seems to generally still link to overall reproductive activity and function?), is it still tied to general sex drive and libido levels, as its absence correlating to low libido—and its seemingly higher quantities/strengths occurring with particularly high libido—suggests?

For a particular example, asexual people are a diverse group with varying properties regarding their individual sex health or habits, but there are many who report having a naturally low libido for most of their life (without distress). A level as low as, or lower than, the level at which a typical person experiencing a sudden drop in libido—and a lack of spontaneous erections as a result—would “fall” to. Would these asexual people with naturally, consistently low libido (so not a sudden change, as in the context of the people with typical libidos experiencing a new and temporary drop, but instead a default and non-distressing state) just as a result of that low libido naturally experience these spontaneous erections less—less often, weaker, both?

Answer (score 1):

I think that libido and spontaneous erections could possibly have a correlation as you say, since usually the explanation for spontaneous erections is a surge of estrogen, progesterone, and testosterone which could cause a high sex drive. Low amounts of those hormones could possibly cause low libido and thus cause low spontaneous erections, although if your interested in primarily testosterone and their effects on men, their are different forms with their potentially varying effects on libido. I think these studies could help you get a better look at this topic:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5649360/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2586969/